# Why new shapefile is not appearing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-3, vector-layer

In QGIS 3.24.2 I have just opened a new project and when I add a new shapefile layer it brings up a box saying that the layer already exists and asking if I want to overwrite it. However, I haven't added anything or changed anything.

The projection is set to the default EPSG:4326 and I am almost certain this is compatible with the shapefile, however when I click <kbd>Yes</kbd> to overwrite nothing appears. I've tried zooming to layer but still, absolutely nothing appears on the screen.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: It is a difference between creating a new shapefile and loading a new shapefile in the project, see here : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html#sample-session-loading-raster-and-vector-layers

Comment: @BenW It half answers it, thank you, it explains why it was asking about overwriting. However, when I either 'add vector layer' (as opposed to creating) or drag the file into qGIS I still get a blank screen and empty attribute table

Comment: so your shapefile is a new and empty, so you can create geometries in it. If your shapefile must have geometries, have you all the shapefile sidecar files or are you sure you didn't overwrite it with a new shapefile by creating it ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking, I'm afraid I'm very new to using qGIS. I have opened a brand new project, then selected 'add vector layer'. Here I selected and then added the 'ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp' from the Working with Projections Tutorial. This was added and has appeared in layers but has a blank attribute table and no presence on the screen.

Comment: @KateaClover: remove this shapefile from your QGIS project, redownload it or re-extract it from the downloaded archive because I think you overwrite it with a blank new shapefile created in QGIS, so now you try to open it, it's empty.

Comment: @J.Monticolo Just tried that and its working now, thank you very much for your help